# CAKEPHP: index.ctp Not Working

Tags: cakephp

http://pastebin.com/PWJvwMF6
http://webdesign4.georgianc.on.ca/~100141468/comp2084/todo/clients/

As you can see that is the error that keeps appearing. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Does the code in the pastebin look okay? Or is there a clear issue there. If not, could it be that my controller has a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `'` on line 12

```
<?=$row['Client']['employee_id]?>
```

should be

```
<?=$row['Client']['employee_id']?>
                              ^
```

Comment: As you can see now when they are clicked on I am going no where. I am assuming I made a mistake by adding an s at the end?

Comment: No... capitalized... that's the issue

Comment: Create your links with `echo $this->Html->link('View', array('controller' => 'clients', 'action' => 'view', $row['Client']['id']));` and similarly for your other links.

Comment: So I replace my links in index.php with variations of that?

Comment: Add works now, but the rest do not. http://pastebin.com/4Z75bXkS What is missing here? Also, notice anything wrong with the 'inner join' part?

Comment: index.ctp, yes, and anywhere were you use links really. The benefit of using the Html Helper is that it will do reverse routing for you. If you ever change the structure of your urls, you dont have to go back and edit your views.

Comment: You should also use <?php, not short-tags.

Comment: Okay, thanks. This cake stuff is pretty neat; saves everyone a lot of time.

Comment: If there are other issues not related to this question, start a question.